Confidence interval - CLT, beginner level
I'm taking an online course about statistics and more precisely about the confidence interval.
Below is an exercise in which they are trying to estimate the number of shoes that can be sold for each based on previous data collected.
as shown bellow line 7 represent the months and column B represent the shoes sizes.
the table represent the frequency distribution.

1- if we take the shoes size 6 (line 8), they calculated the confidence interval which is between [1.8-4.04].
according to my humble knowledge, i know that the confidence interval is only calculated on a normal distribution. but i can't see how the distribution table for shoes size 6 can form a normal distribution ?
am i right ?
I know that, if the sample distribution is not normal, we can use the CLT, which means the average of sample which has a normal distribution. is it possible to apply that on shoes size 6 (line 8) ?

2- why the standard error was calculated? I thought the standard error only apply for the sample of means (CLT) and in line 8 the data are not sample means but normal distribution.

also the denominator of the standard error formula represent the number of sample means but it's not the case.
can someone please clarify me the ambiguity?
thanks,

A few observations.
Wrt to your first question (normality of the data), what needs to be normally distributed is the sampling distribution of the mean, not the raw data. Now, if the raw data itself is normally distributed that is a sufficient condition for the sampling distribution of the mean to be normally distributed. But is is not a necessary condition.
You are also correct in stating that the CLT can ensure that the sampling distribution of the mean will be normally distributed, asymptotically (ie for large enough sample sizes). What is large enough? It depends... Most textbooks will say something like 30; I do not know what this based on, and I doubt it has some solid basis. If you take a (well-bahaved) uniform distribution, the CLT will converge with as low as 5 datapoints. A reasonable, one-humped, non-horribly skewed distribution will converge with ~10 samples (e.g. $\chi^2$ with 5 d.f.). An exponential distribution (very skewed) may need 30-ish observations. A log-normal distribution may need several 100's. You may want to read this blog or this paper. This link and this other one have nice simulations. And with a sample size of 12 in your case, the CLT may or may not not be quite up to the task. Also, with such small sample size, eyeballing the distribution, or using normality tests, is a futile exercise (the probative value, whether it fails or passes, is quite low).
So I think the authors are asking you to take it "on faith" , or to simply ignore that aspect; this exercise is probably more meant to teach the "mechanics" of CI's (i.e. how to calculate them), rather than going into the rigor of how much you could trust these CI's.
Note that the 1-sample t-test is fairly robust to reasonable departure from normality (see e.g. here on CV). With only 12 observations, it would be hard to find an "extreme departure from normality" (basically fat tails, large kurtosis).
With respect to the 2nd question, yourr formla is correct. But practicallty, we never know the true population $\sigma$. So we estimate it with the sample sd, $s$ (see here on wiki), just like we estimate $\mu$ with $\bar x$. The standard error was estimated because it is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the mean; and that is what we need, because the observed mean $\bar x$ belongs to this sampling distribution. To compute the CI, you multiply the estimate of the SE, by a t critical value (for sample size of 12, and significance of $\alpha=.05$, which the Excel sheet shows as 2.18 ($CI=\bar x \pm t.se$).
Additional observations; the spreadsheet seems to play loose with rounding. For example, the "exact" CI for row 8 is [1.7847,4.0487]; this gets rounded to [1.80, 4.04]. It really should be (with 2 significant digits) [1.78, 4.05]. They show the t critical value as 2.18, but it really is 2.199.
And to answer the question "what are the number of shoes that are likely to be sold", they pick the upper bound of the CI of the mean, which is an odd choice of an estimator?
